# How can I solve by using the combinations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Form a group of $8$ women and $6$ man, committee consisting of $3$ men and $3$ women is to be formed. In how many ways can the committee be formed if two of the men refuses to serve together?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: find the number of all possibilities and subtract the number of possibilities with the two hostiles in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the men be X and Y who refuses to serve together.

Initially, let's find out the number of ways in which the committee can be formed by excluding both X and Y.

We excluded both X and Y. Hence we need to select $3$ men from $4$ women $(=6-2)$ and $3$ women from $8$ women. Number of ways in which this can be done
$=~ ^4C_3~ × ~^8C_3 \tag1$

Now let's find out the number of ways in which the committee can be formed where exactly one man from X and Y will be present.

i.e., we need to select one man from two men (X and Y), remaining $2$ men from $4$ men $(=6-2)$ and $3$ women from $8$ women. Number of ways in which this can be done
$=~ ^2C_1 ~×~ ^4C_2 ~×~ ^8C_3 \tag2$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,
Number of ways in which a committee can be formed if two of the women refuses to serve together
$$= \left(~^4C_3 ~× ~^8C_3\right) + \left(~^2C_1~ ×~ ^4C_2 ~×~ ^8C_3\right)$$
$$= ~^8C_3~\left(~^4C_3 ~+~ ^2C_1 ~×~ ^4C_2 \right)$$
$$= 56~\left(~4+2\cdot 6\right)$$
$$=896$$